# How to create a list from two values?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Wasn't sure how to write a good title for this question... :)

I'm new to Linq and not sure what syntax to use for this problem I have

```
class MainClass()
{
  string MainKey {get;set;}
  string MainName {get;set;}
  List<SmallObject> MainList {get;set}
}

class SmallObject()
{
  string SmallKey {get;set}
}
```

Linq:

myTable contains of 4 string fields (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)

```
var mainQuery = (from v from myTable
                 select v)    

var myQuery = (from v in mainQuery
               select new MainClass()
               {
                MainKey = v.Field1,
                MainName = v.Field2,
                MainList = #whats the correct syntax here?#
               })
```

The part marked with #whats the correct syntax here?# is my problem.
I want to add v.Field3 and v.Field4 as items to the MainList-object in MainClass, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm happy  if anyone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `List<T>` (or any other collection) and add items to it with a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
MainList = new List<SmallObject> { v.Field3, v.Field4 }
```

**Update:**

Since `Field3` and `Field4` are strings, you would just do what you already do to make them into `SmallObject`s:

```
MainList = new List<SmallObject>
{ 
    new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field3 },
    new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field4 },
}
```

Or, you could add a `SmallObject` constructor that takes a string argument and use it like `new SmallObject(v.Field3)`.

Comment: It's a little unclear, he might also be trying to do something like `MainList = new { Field3PropLabel = v.Field3, Field4PropLabel = v.Field4 }`

Comment: Will that work? v.Field3 is of type string, not of type SmallObject

Comment: No the type will have to match if you want to use a List<T> to store them. If you are after an anonymous class though, it will work just fine.

Comment: @user703494: You should have provided this information in the first place, since it's important, but it doesn't change much: you need to provide the conversion from `string` to `SmallObject` yourself (obviously).

Comment: I thought maybe i could write
MainList = new List<SmallObject> {
              new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field3 },
              new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field4 }
          }
but that doesn't seem to work. The MainList doesn't get populated

Comment: @user703494 - provide a `SmallObject` constructor taking `String` to allow proper init of `SmallKey` in the code above.  Is that what you need?

Comment: @asawyer: Class members cannot be of an anonymous type, so eventually if the data is to be put into a `MainClass` it will have to be converted.

Comment: @user703494: It should certainly work. If it doesn't then something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I was on the right track it seemed.
But I get an exception when calling .ToList() on the myQuery-variable; NotSupportedException: Cannot create query result of Type System.Collections.Generic.List'1 [SmallObject]

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understand you correctly. But the following works for me:

```
var myTable = new [] {
            new {Field1 = "a", Field2 = "b", Field3 = "c", Field4 = "d"},
            new {Field1 = "a", Field2 = "b", Field3 = "c", Field4 = "d"}
        };



        var myQuery = (from v in myTable
                       select new MainClass()
                       {
                        MainKey = v.Field1,
                        MainName = v.Field2,
                        MainList = new List<SmallObject>{
                            new SmallObject {SmallKey = v.Field3},
                            new SmallObject {SmallKey = v.Field4},
                        }
                       });
```

myQuery is filled with 2 objects (MainClass), with both a Mainlist, each containting 2 items (SmallObject).

Btw, don't really see what the following line is for:

```
var mainQuery = (from v from myTable
             select v)
```

But as I said, maybe I don't understand you correctly

GL!