# Problem getting same result from DataContext.Translate

Tags: linq, anonymous-types, translate, strong-typing

This question is a follow up to this question:
[How to create a list from two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454278/how-to-create-a-list-from-two-values)

Consider this code:

```
class MainClass() 
{
   string MainKey {get;set;}
   string MainName {get;set;}
   IEnumerable<SmallObject> MainList {get;set} 
}

class SmallObject() 
{
   string SmallKey {get;set} 
}
```

and:

```
var mainQuery = (from v from DataContext.myTable
                 select v);

var myQuery = (from v in mainQuery
               select new MainClass()
               {
                  MainKey = v.Field1,
                  MainName = v.Field2,
                  MainList = new []
                  {
                     new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field3 },
                     new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field4 },
                  }
                });


var result1 = myQuery.ToList();

//Changing datatypes for optimization reasons in SQLServer2000
var cmd = DataContext.GetCommand(myQuery);
foreach (System.Data.Common.DbParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
{
  // nvarchar -> varchar
  // decimal -> numeric
}
var result2 = DataContext.Translate<MainClass>(cmd.ExecuteReader()).ToList();
```

result1.MainList is OK

result2.MainList is null

The original query was very slow running on SQLServer2000, and I got it fixed when changing datatypes (Linq uses nvarchar and decimal, as my database use varchar and numeric)

So I want result2 to be the same as result1, but that doesn't happen when doing a DataContext.Translate like this.

Any thoughts of getting the same result here?

I've also tryed  anonymous types, like this:

```
IEnumerable<object> MainList {get;set;}
...
MainList = new []
{
   new { SmallKey = v.Field3},
   new { SmallKey = v.Field4},
}
```

but the result is the same:

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking too much from Translate.

If I understand you correctly, it is the first query (mainQuery) that is too slow, so I would look to replace it.

I would create a simpler temporary class like

```
 public class TmpClass
 {
    public string Field1 {get;set;}
    public string Field2 {get;set;}
    public string Field3 {get;set;}
    public string Field4 {get;set;}
 }
```

Once the list is in this format, you can use the second query to change it to a list of MainClass.

Just a matter of interest, what is the difference between the sql outputted by Linq and your customized version? Unless it is does some casting, I would not expect this type of query to need optimizing.

Comment: The difference is the datatype. For some reason nvarchar and decimal didn't run very well on a SQL2000-base with datatypes varchar and numeric. I search different forums and found others with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [AsEnumerable extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) which basically converts the `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable` which forces the enumerator to be processed. You could achieve the same thing by calling `ToArray()` or `ToList()` but `AsEnumerable()` magically lets you return it back to an `IQueryable` by calling `AsQueryable()`

So probably doing the following will work for you:

```
var result1 = DataContext.myTable.AsEnumerable()
  .Select(v=> new MainClass {
                  MainKey = v.Field1,
                  MainName = v.Field2,
                  MainList = new []
                  {
                     new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field3 },
                     new SmallObject { SmallKey = v.Field4 },
                  }
         });
```